# How can I add videos to my questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

How can I send a video to you to show what's going on when I'm logging on Ubuntu 18.04?

I have a problem that involves a sequence of events and I need to show a video to explain the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use a video camera to record a video of the screen, upload it to your favourite file or video hosting service and add a link to it to your question.

Unfortunately there's no good way to record the screen content at this stage of display and session management. You may want to look into different means to convey to us what's happening and you're welcome to [ask for one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Hardware solution to a software problem!  **+1**

Comment: is OP would be able to see your answer? He got only 1 rep, he needs 5 rep to have access to meta

Comment: @damadam meta is public and can be read by anyone. The reputation restriction on participation applies to posting questions and answers on meta. It is also possible for users with < 5 rep to ask questions on meta by using a restricted format to ask about a specific question of their own on the main site